# How to create cross-scene references in a timeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a project that has a player scene, and a level scene. How do I allow tracks inside the timeline to reference objects in both of these scenes?

The timeline does allow you to fill the editor fields with references from objects in other scenes, but those are lost when you exit playmode. I presume this is because it uses the instanceID's which are lost when they get regenerated?

I currently use a GUID-based system to store editor-time cross-scene references, although I am not sure how I would implement this into the timeline.

Comment: it will if both scenes are loaded i think, but also you woulld need both loaded to make it run

Comment: Even if both scenes are loaded simply entering and exiting playmode still causes them to lose the reference. So far I've decided to simply inject the references directly into the PlayableDirector instead

Comment: There's a free [asset on the asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/advanced-multi-scene-cross-scene-references-47200) that handles cross scene references. Maybe looking at the source code will help you figuring it out